# Was Cobra Kai influenced by How I Met Your Mother?

Tags: production, how-i-met-your-mother, karate-kid, cobra-kai

In How I Met Your Mother a recurring joke was that Barney "doesn't get movies", so in the Karate Kid he roots for Johnny Lawrence whom he claims to be the actual karate kid.

Later, Robin organizes a bachelor party for Barney and invites "the wrong Karate Kid", Ralph Macchio who is all suited up and kind of a Barney.

Now, YouTube has released via YouTube Red a new series continuing the events of The Karate Kid in which Johnny Lawrence is down on his luck (and apparently never got over his illegal defeat), and Daniel LaRusso is a suit-clad business man who is (at least a little bit) like Barney.

They even bring up the illegal face-kick thing, something that was also mentioned once or twice by Barney.

> Was there any inspiration from the How I Met Your Mother incorporation of Billy Zabka and the Karate Kid when deciding to make the Cobra Kai series?

Comment: Let me also clarify that I only watched the trailer and the first episode so far. So I might be getting things wrong.

Comment: Ink, later on they show more images of the past from the point of view of Johnny in contradiction with what the movie showed. How he remember those moments and how he felt. I finished it and it was greater than I thought it will be when I started it. Maybe the HIMYM brought the idea but is not entirely "one is the good guy and the other isnt". I loved how the history repeats itself even same scenarios and places from the movie.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Build Series](https://www.buildseries.com/video/5aea1a0e9f25116866826236/) has a video where Billy Zabka and Ralph Macchio talk briefly about their time on the set of How I Met Your Mother, and how they took a photo at the end of their time on How I Met Your Mother, and when they sat down with the creators for Cobra Kai they talked about their ideas and they morphed into something much bigger.

Whether the show creators were further influenced, I do not know.  But it certainly looks like both the main actors had their influences from their time on the show.